# ¿Hay una buena descripcion del concepto FlagArgument en castellano?

Tags: refactoring

(Disculpa por mi bajo nivel de castellano - soy ingles trabajando en España)

Estoy intentando a explicar el concepto [FlagArgument](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html) a mis compañeros, pero no puedo encontrar ninguna cosa escrita en castellano sobre eso.

He intentado buscar por Google usando palabras claves "FlagArgument" y "español" o "castellano" pero no he encontrado nada. Quiza no estoy buscando por el nombre correcto. ¿El concepto se llama igual?

Puedo explicarlo mas o menos bien si estamos hablando, pero tarda tiempo y nunca estoy seguro si me entienden bien. Por eso me gustaria tener algo escrita que puedo enviar.

Comment: básicamente, es un booleano que se usa para realizar ciertas acciones dependiendo de su valor, ¿no?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo exacto - es algo que puedes refactorizar por crear dos implementaciones en lugar de uno grande. esa pagina de Martin Fowler describelo bien, con ejemplos en codigo, y es algo asi que estoy buscando

Comment: siendo sincero, jamás escuché acerca del término. lo más cerca a lo que leí en el artículo, sería el explicar como funcionan los booleanos, o **banderas**

Comment: no sé si esto te sea de utilidad, pero lo dejo por aquí. ¿buscas para algún lenguaje en específico?: http://escueladeprogramacion.es/snippets/Java/Algoritmos/Bandera.html

Comment: @L.Ronquillo gracias por el enlace, sí, es explicar como banderas no deberan ser usado demasiado :-) y la verdad es que, antes del blog ese de Sr. Fowler en 2011, el concepto tampoco tenia nombre conocido en ingles. Por eso es dificil a encontrar, creo.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo y no busco para algun lenguaje en especifico. Trabajamos predominamente en Python, pero el concepto puede ser describido en cualquier lenguaje de programacion y seria bien